# How to avoid TS2322 "Type any is not assignable to type never" when using indexed access

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, tsc

Given the following code:

```
interface MyInterface {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

function modify(o: MyInterface, attrName: keyof MyInterface, attrValue: any) {
    o[attrName] = attrValue; // <-- typescript compiler error on this line
}
```

I get a typescript compiler error `TS2322: Type any is not assignable to type never` on the `t[attrName] = attrValue` line.

How can I avoid this compiler error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on your function, and use the type parameters to restrict the `attrValue`:

```
interface MyInterface {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

function modify<T, K extends keyof T>(t: T, attrName: K, attrValue: T[K]) {
    t[attrName] = attrValue;
}
```

Comment: careful, `T` wasn't a generic type in the original question!

Comment: I updated the original code (the name T was a bad name for an interface).

Comment: I edited this answer as well (interface T->interface MyInterface). The example code in the answer is still correct, right? @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: Still correct. You could limit yourself to just using `K extends keyof MyInterface` as a type parameter and then type the value as `MyInterface[K]`, but might as well go full generic as the answer is currently written.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a type assertion to tell TypeScript that the value of attrValue is compatible with the type of t[attrName]. An example of this would be:

```
function modifyT(t: T, attrName: keyof T, attrValue: any) {
    t[attrName] = attrValue as T[keyof T]; // <-- no error
}
```

So if you do this then TypeScript will assume that attrValue is either a string or a number, depending on the value of attrName and consequently will not complain about assigning any to never.

Apart from this you may also choose to use a generic type parameter for attrValue, and constrain it to the type of t[attrName]. An exmaple of this would be:

```
function modifyT<K extends keyof T>(t: T, attrName: K, attrValue: T[K]) {
    t[attrName] = attrValue; // <-- no error
}
```

If you do this then TypeScript will infer the type of attrValue from the type of attrName, and ensure that they are compatible